# How to "copy/paste" a subgraph -- JointJS

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, jointjs, subgraph

I try to add a copy paste option in my program but links doesn't come with.
All my blocks are well copied but my links aren't.

```
var copied;
$("#copy").click(function(){
    var papa = block_menu.model; //clicked element
    var copied_cells=papa.clone({deep:true}); //take all embedded cells
    copied=graph.getSubgraph(copied_cells, {deep:true}); //copy
});
$("#paste").click(function(){   
    graph.addCells(copied); //paste (add on graph)
});
```

I've tried to add this before `"copied = ...."` but that doesn't change anything :

> var copied_cells = graph.getSubgraph(copied_cells)
>   `

Does someone nows how to copy my links with?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

cells should be sorted before you're putting them back into graph. **Elements first, then links.** `addCells` has been adding cells as it is, so if there is link whose target/source is not in the graph yet, this link won't be added.